# Accessing XML objects as CLIENT.ADDRESS.STATE 

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, xml-parsing

```
CLIENT
  NAME
    FIRSTNAME
    LASTNAME
  ADDRESS
    ADD1
    ADD2
    CITY
    STATE
    ZIP
```

Imagine the above in an XML document (Its easy if you try...)

Would like to be able to refer to an XML (or other) object that now is:

CLIENT.NAME.FIRSTNAME = "LoriBeth"

Is this possible?  From looking at and playing with XML objects, it does not appear to be so.

Comment: I don't think there's any built-in functionality to convert XML to objects in such a transparent fashion, but there is LINQ to XML, as well as XPath.

Comment: See this answer on shashdot, he does exactly that:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283040/deserialize-xml-string-to-complex-type

Comment: Problem is, I would like to be able to do this on the fly, not hard code everything before hand. Would like to be able to call a function with an XML object as the parameter and have it return an object or have the XML object itself be adressable like we have it. Without being able to create properties from strings discovered at runtime, I cannot make this function.. :(